# Call JavaScript function from native code

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, native-module

I have a react-native app and want to integrate it with native SDK. At some point I need to call js function which will return me data, and this call I should make from native side. Here is the flow:

1. some iOS handler require more info
2. native layer calls js code
3. js code calculate/fetch required data
4. js code return data back to native code
5. native code receive data and continue working

Is it possible? There is a lib [`react-native-eval`](https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-eval) but may be there is more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [Callbacks](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#callbacks) or [Sending Events to JavaScript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @DheerajV.S. but both of them are work in order to deliver data or notify react-native from native layer. I need to pass data in reverse order

Comment: Hi, @Alexei Malashkevich did you find any solution for this? I am also stuck in this.

Comment: @AshishSinghal did you find anything I'm also stuck here :(

Comment: @Imran the correct way is to use an Event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no clean way of doing this. My suggestion would be to use either a [Callback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#callbacks) or an [Event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript) from native to JS to notify that there is some information needed and to then invoke a function from JS to the native code that gives the required data to the native layer.